# Use-case actor with many behaviors

Tags: oop, ooad

I'm trying to imagine how a use-case actor with multiple behaviors actually shows up in the application.

Take the following real world but oversimplified case:

An environmental consulting organization has a project manager responsible for: creating and managing clients; projects; facilities and buildings, and equipment and supplies. A lot of this is just CRUD, but there's quite a bit more.

Does it make sense to have a ProjectManager class with all the behaviors implied? Just looking at the use-case diagram, I can see 20+ methods that would be required.

[Project Management Use-Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr73J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting all the eggs into a one basket, why don't you group responsibilities in different "roles" and then assign these roles to PM?

What I mean by that is, please bear with me and imagine:

Interface: CustomerRelations
Responsibilities: customer related ops (e.g. create customer, keep good relations with them etc)

Interface: OfficeManagement
Responsibilities: acquire necessary equipment to do business, and provide necessary supply to use them etc.

Interface: ProjectManagement
Responsibilities: monitor and supervise projects etc

And them

Class: ProjectManager implements CustomerRelations, OfficeManagement and ProjectManagement.

This way, you can easily re-shuffle responsibilities around if need be.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thanks.

I was thinking about breaking down the project manager into sub managers, but your answer is obviously the better approach.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

We can also imagine like this. Adding to answer from @Alp

> A project manager has X number of responsibilities.(Customer
>   Relations, Office Management)

Interface: CustomerRelations Responsibilities: customer related ops (e.g. Get-feedback from customer, and other)

Interface: OfficeManagement Responsibilities:

Class: ProjectManager can have ICustomerRelations, IOfficeManagement and IProjectManagement.

```
Class ProjectManager
{
   IOfficeManagerment officeManagement;
   ICustomerRelations  customerRelations;

    public ProjectManager(IOfficeManagerment management, ICustomerRelations)
    {
          \\Inject your dependencies
    }


    public void GetFeedBack()
    {
        customerRelations.GetFeedback();
    }

    public void GetEquipements()
    {
        officeManagement.GetAvailableEquipments();
    }
}
```

Considerations

1. Project-manager doesn't have to know internals how the office is
   managed. He delegate the duty to some other. eg. How to get
   available resources. He just want to know the available resources.